# In Ubuntu 23.10, xset led 3 and xset -led 3 do not work for wired keyboards

Tags: keyboard, backlight, xset

I have a USB cable keyboard and the LED light is not working, but on this same laptop it was working on Ubuntu version 22.04, now xset commands etc. are not working

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1.

1. open terminal
2. write this command `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

   3.find this line "#WaylandEnable=true" remove the [#] sign and change true to false
3. ctrl+s for save and ctrl+x for exit
4. reboot your laptop
5. open terminal
6. xset led on [Enter]